# pfSense Shell : apply config modification without reboot

Tags: firewall, shell, pfsense, automation

I'm currently trying to edit the configuration of a running pfSense in production with the pfSsh.php shell. By using the [pfSsh.php](https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Using_the_PHP_pfSense_Shell) shell I'm able to modify the configuration but once I write it, it isn't applied to the system.

Is there a way to force a configuration reload without rebooting the whole system ?

```
pfSense shell: $newIp['mode'] = 'ipalias';
pfSense shell: $newIp['interface'] = 'wan';
pfSense shell: $newIp['descr'] = 'vip1';
pfSense shell: $newIp['type'] = 'single';
pfSense shell: $newIp['subnet_bits'] = 24;
pfSense shell: $newIp['subnet'] = '192.168.0.241';
pfSense shell: $config['virtualip']['vip'][] = $newIp;
pfSense shell: parse_config(true);
pfSense shell: write_config();
pfSense shell: exec;
```

If I print the configuration, I can see that the vip is added :

```
     [virtualip] => Array
       (
           [vip] => Array
               (
                   [0] => Array
                       (
                           [mode] => ipalias
                           [interface] => wan
                           [uniqid] => 578aa9852a7bf
                           [descr] => test
                           [type] => single
                           [subnet_bits] => 24
                           [subnet] => 192.168.0.239
                       )

                   [1] => Array
                       (
                           [mode] => ipalias
                           [interface] => wan
                           [descr] => Unused IP
                           [type] => single
                           [subnet_bits] => 24
                           [subnet] => 192.168.0.241
```

But on the system, the vip isn't added until I reboot :

```
[2.3.1-RELEASE][admin@pfSense.localdomain]/root: ifconfig
em0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
       options=9b<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_MTU,VLAN_HWTAGGING,VLAN_HWCSUM>
       ether 00:0c:29:22:55:0b
       inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:fe22:550b%em0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1
       inet 192.168.0.240 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.0.255
```

**EDIT :**

Thanks to Chris answer I used the interface_ipalias_configure method which worked as expected. I put a simple looping example which add multiple vips from 192.168.0.74 to 79 to a CARP VIP, if it can help someone.

This php script is written /etc/phpshellsessions/myscript and executed through " pfSsh.php playback myscript" command in a remote console as admin.

```
$vipPrefix = '192.168.0.';
$vipNetmask = '24';

foreach($config['virtualip']['vip'] as $k => $value) {
   $tmp[] = $value['subnet'];
}

end($config['virtualip']['vip']);

$vID = key($config['virtualip']['vip']);

for ($i = 74; $i < 80; $i++) {

    $byte = strval($i);

    if ( ! in_array( $vipPrefix.$byte , $tmp )) {

        $vID++;
        $newIp['mode'] = 'ipalias';
        $newIp['interface'] = '_vip57cc61f85d2c8';
        $newIp['descr'] = $vipPrefix.$byte;
        $newIp['type'] = 'single';
        $newIp['subnet_bits'] = $vipNetmask;
        $newIp['subnet'] = $vipPrefix.$byte;
        $newIp['uniqid'] = uniqid();
        $config['virtualip']['vip'][$vID] = $newIp;
        parse_config(true);
        write_config();
        interface_ipalias_configure($config['virtualip']['vip'][$vID]);
    }
}

print_r($config['virtualip']['vip']);

exec;
```

Comment: You know what, Nevermind. I'm wrong. Your script *is* editing the xml config.

Comment: I cannot use the Web GUI, the purpose is to automate pfsense configuration modification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing there is only changing the config. That much of it's correct, but then you need to apply those changes.

For the case of VIPs, check what firewall_virtual_ip.php does when you apply changes. 
https://github.com/pfsense/pfsense/blob/master/src/usr/local/www/firewall_virtual_ip.php#L48

Do that in your code after doing the write_config.